# Adding machines from outside the network on Landscape Dedicated Server

Tags: landscape

I've got a Landscape Dedicated Server set up and working fine on my local network with various machines added.

I'd like to add some external machines, however I am unable to communicate with the server using the `landscape-config` command. I've forwarded the HTTPS and HTTP ports of the server and it is able to communicate outside the network (i.e. I am able to access the Landscape login page in a browser from the external machine I am trying to add).

In the command to add the external machine (below), I've tried:

- using the machine name (after adding it to `/etc/hosts`)
- the IP of the server
- creating a DNS entry to point to the server

Here is the command.

```
sudo landscape-config --computer-title "name" --account-name standalone --url https://<attempts-listed-above>/message-system --ping-url http://<attempts-listed-above>/ping
```

Every time I've been met with this error message:

```
We were unable to contact the server. Your internet connection may be down. The 
landscape client will continue to try and contact the server periodically.
```

Any suggestions or ideas are very much appreciated! Having a very difficult time getting this to work and am running out of ideas to try and get these machines added!

---

Update... Thank you for the comment @dpb.

### Ubuntu 16.04

A fresh version of Ubuntu 16.04 added without issue! OpenSSL version is `1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`.

The command you suggested I run ended with:

```
openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> < /dev/null
```

returns (trimmed):

```
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

### Ubuntu 14.04

However, I cannot get any Ubuntu 14.04 machines to add. OpenSSL version is `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`.

```
openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> < /dev/null
```

returns (trimmed):

```
Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

`/var/log/landscape/broker.log` contains:

```
2016-10-04 17:28:49,490 INFO     [MainThread] Queueing message to register with account 'standalone' in access group 'ny' and tags ny without a password.
2016-10-04 17:28:49,491 INFO     [MainThread] Starting urgent message exchange with https://<server>:<port>/message-system.
2016-10-04 17:28:49,688 ERROR    [PoolThread-twisted.internet.reactor-1] Error contacting the server at https://<server>:<port>/message-system.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/broker/transport.py", line 71, in exchange
    message_api)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/broker/transport.py", line 45, in _curl
    headers=headers, cainfo=self._pubkey, curl=curl))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/landscape/lib/fetch.py", line 109, in fetch
    raise PyCurlError(e.args[0], e.args[1])
PyCurlError: Error 51: gnutls_handshake() warning: The server name sent was not recognized
2016-10-04 17:28:49,688 INFO     [MainThread] Message exchange failed.
2016-10-04 17:28:49,689 INFO     [MainThread] Message exchange completed in 0.20s.
```

Any further suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Landscape uses a certificate to validate communication.  Even if it's self-signed, the CN or subj_alt_name needs to be correct, or the client will reject it.  Are you sure the cert is correct?  You can use `openssl s_client -connect IP:443 < /dev/null` to inspect the cert yourself.  Also please attach the `/var/log/landscape/broker.log` after sanitizing, if you would like.

Comment: @dpb thank you for the comment, please see my updated answer

Comment: what's "external" mean, exactly?  On the other side of a firewall?  can you describe more of the setup (e.g. what's doing the NATing and ACLing?)

Comment: @James Our company gave up and scrapped the project. Canonical issued us a refund. However, for reference, external simply meant that it wasn't on the same local network as the Landscape server.

Comment: Ok, should you decide to give it another look, Landscape can easily do what you are asking about. 90% of Landscape install issues are certificate related. The other 10% are traditional linux issues (eg networking).